# Renaming the images in ipad

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad

Is there any way to rename the images present in ipad photo library.I want to rename them in ipad itself.Is it possible?

Thanks,
Christy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Photo-Sort](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photo-sort-for-ipad-organize/id369610590?mt=8) app, $1,99.

As far as I know, you need a (Intel) Mac to write and program Cocoa. You can type in on an iPad, but you won't be able to code it

Comment: Thanks Michiel,but is there any other thing which i can code to make this happen rather than going for a third party app

Comment: Thanks @Michiel,but is there any other thing which i can code to make this happen rather than going for a third party app

Comment: @Christina, so you want to rename the images in Cocoa **on** the iPad itself? Normally, you write your code in XCode, no?

Comment: yes ,that is what i wanted ,i want to have a button in my view controller which when i will click will provide the option of renaming the images in my library,can u help me with this @Michiel

Comment: @Christina, I would love to help you, but as far as I know, you need a (Intel) Mac to write and program Cocoa. You can type in on an iPad, but you won't be able to code it.

Comment: i have a mac ,can u describe how to type it on ipad and save with the new name

Comment: I have not that much experience in Cocoa, but for starters, you can subscribe yourself to the developers program of Apple. For $99 a year, you have access to all the tools, documentation, API,... you need to accomplish this.

Comment: ok can i do like this ,i am taking my image from library then renaming it and then storing it in my app bundle,do u know anything which could help me with this

Comment: I'm terrible sorry, I don't know enough Cocoa to help you with this... I hope you do find someone else.